# kubectl: Get location of KubeConfig file in use

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When I'm using `kubectl` on top of Kubernetes. I can view contents of `KUBECONFIG` file like this:

```sh
$ kubectl config view
```

Is there any way I can find out which I can find out the location of `KUBECONFIG` file `kubectl` is using? I'm looking for something like:

```sh
$ kubectl config get-location
/path/to/kube-config/file
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68172643/finding-the-kubeconfig-file-being-used/68172779#68172779

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75337632/how-does-kubectl-know-which-kubeconfig-config-file-to-use

Answer (score 21):

The kubeconfig directory is default to `$HOME/.kube/config`. But it can be overwritten by `$KUBECONFIG` env.

To get your kubeconfig directory, run:

```sh
$ [[ ! -z "$KUBECONFIG" ]] && echo "$KUBECONFIG" || echo "$HOME/.kube/config"
```

**What it does?** If `$KUBECONFIG` is set, print the value. Otherwise, print the default value.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I'm aware of `KUBECONFIG` environment variable but I was looking if there is an option supported in `kubectl` to print which kubeconfig file is it loading.

Comment: How would you know which `kubeconfig` is in use when your `KUBECONFIG` environment variable contains multiple files?

Comment: Hi @RohanKumar while scouring documentation i found this 
- "If KUBECONFIG contains multiple paths, the first one is used."
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68172643/finding-the-kubeconfig-file-being-used/68172779#68172779