# Finding the kubeconfig file being used

Tags: kubernetes, automation, kubectl, kubeconfig

I understand kubectl gets the kubeconfig file in the order

1. command line option `--kubeconfig`
2. environment variable `KUBECONFIG=`
3. default path `~/.kube/config`

But is there a way to get the kubeconfig path/file details from the kubectl which one being currently used?

Something like `kubectl config path`

Comment: [kubectl: Get location of KubeConfig file in use [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64346151/kubectl-get-location-of-kubeconfig-file-in-use)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Question: But is there a way to get the kubeconfig path/file details from the kubectl which one being currently used?**

Yes, you can run any `kubectl` command with `verbose` level 6+ to see the `kubeconfig` in use.

```
kubectl get pod   -v6                                             
I0629 04:48:25.050954   14444 loader.go:379] Config loaded from file:  /home/ps/.kube/config
I0629 04:48:25.146072   14444 round_trippers.go:445] GET https://kubemaster:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?limit=500 200 OK in 10 milliseconds
No resources found in default namespace.
```

Few examples demonstrating the same:

```
kubectl get pod   -v6 2>&1 |awk  '/Config loaded from file:/{print $NF}'
/home/ps/.kube/config
```

Changed the`kubeconfig` to `/tmp/config`

```
export KUBECONFIG=/tmp/config    
kubectl get pod   -v6 2>&1 |awk  '/Config loaded from file:/{print $NF}'
/tmp/config
```

Remove the `awk` command to see the whole output.

Windows output:

[image]

Comment: It seems this is either already broken, or never worked properly on Windows. I'm using v1.22.0 of `kubectl`, and no verbosity level of any command prints that first line =/

Comment: I just checked it is working, adding the screenshot for reference

Comment: worked for me as well. There was a .kube folder in my windows user home directory, but the kubectl config was loading from the home directory of the SSH client i was using. This command helped me find out the additional .kube folder in the SSH client's home directory.