# Trying to find kube/config file

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to create a pod with `kubectl apply` but I am getting host error, so I tried searching and found that kubectl reads from kube/config file, hence I am trying to view it but not able to get it. Can anyone please help here?

Below I am pasting my Pastebin of my commands
https://pastebin.com/fq9JmRbe

Comment: ` but I am getting host error` -- Please elaborate it and provide paste commands you are running  and errors in the question dirrectly.

Comment: You can view the config with `kubectl config view` as well.

Comment: check the env if set KUBECONFIG and follow path if file not at .kube/config.

Answer (score 1):

The config file for `kubectl` is normally found at `${HOME}/.kube/config`.  See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64346151/kubectl-get-location-of-kubeconfig-file-in-use).