# How does kubectl know which KUBECONFIG config file to use?

Tags: kubectl

In the past, I used `$HOME/.kube/config` and downloaded the kubeconfig file from Rancher.
There was only one kubeconfig file (see [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/)) so I never wondered about which file was being used.

Yesterday, I switched to using the KUBECONFIG environment variable because there are several k8s clusters I'm now using (prod, stg, dev), and that's what the devops team told me to do, so I did it (and it worked).  For the sake of discussion, the command was:

```
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config-prod:$HOME/.kube/config-stage:$HOME/.kube/config-dev
```

So now I can use following commands to use the staging K8S cluster.

```
kubectl config current-context
# verify I'm in the using the right k8s config, and switch if necessary
kubectl config use-context dev    <<< WHERE DOES kubectl store this setting???
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace MyDeploymentNamespace
kubectl get pods
```

My question is **How does does kubectl know what kube config file is being used? Where does it store the currently selected context?**

or instead

**Does kubectl logically concatenate all of the kubeconfig files defined in the KUBECONFIG environment variable to get access to any of the defined Kubernetes clusters?**

## Searching for answer

I found several answers to similar questions but not quite this question.

- [kubectl: Get location of KubeConfig file in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64346151/kubectl-get-location-of-kubeconfig-file-in-use)  is similar and points to  [Finding the kubeconfig file being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68172643/finding-the-kubeconfig-file-being-used)

Which explains how to the file

```
kubectl config current-context -v6
I0203 14:59:05.926287   30654 loader.go:375] Config loaded from file:  /home/user1/.kube/config
dev
```

**I'm asking where is this information stored?**

The only guess I have is in the $HOME/.kube/cache directory in which I'm finding scores of files.

Some Kubernetes documentation

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:

- [The `KUBECONFIG` environment variable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#the-kubeconfig-environment-variable); and
- [Merging `kubeconfig` files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#merging-kubeconfig-files)

which says:

> Otherwise, if the KUBECONFIG environment variable is set, use it as a list of files that should be merged. Merge the files listed in the KUBECONFIG environment variable according to these rules: (see link for details)

So to answer your question,

> Does kubectl logically concatenate all of the kubeconfig files defined in the KUBECONFIG environment variable . . .

The answer is; the files are merged.

`kubeconfig` files contain sections for `clusters`,`contexts` and `users` and there's a `current-context` property too which stores the value of `kubectl config current-context` and is revised by `kubectl config use-context`.

Per the rules in [Merging `kubeconfig` files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#merging-kubeconfig-files), the first occurrence of e.g. `current-context` is the value that wins.